# What's the purpose of +&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk?

Tags: url-parameters, addthis

When I look at my logs, I see AddThis.com requests URLs with `+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk` appended to the end and therefore it creates a 404.11 error.

What's the purpose of this, if any?

Comment: The purpose is to add extra information to the URL.  Looks like you might be in the (gl=UK) and using English (hl=en), the other parameters could mean anything.  You should contact addthis for more info.